# Can Blender unwrap ngons? Are ngons the reason why UV maps have artefacts as unwanted weirdly stretched UVs

Tags: uv

I want to unwrap two faces. When I select them and press U and Unwrap I get some artefacts as stretched unwanted UVs. What is it? And how can I avoid them?
[image]

Comment: Blender is pretty bad in unwrapping when you want to use it on concave faces. To avoid these artifacts you can triangulate those faces by hitting ctrl+t or you can use the "Projection from view" option in the unwrap menu.

Comment: @FFeller Thanks, I have tried it already, yes it works well with triangulated  faces and it doesn't work with Projection from view (result is the same)

Comment: @FFeller and I try to unwrap only flat faces